# Procedure Declaration Error

Tags: vb6

As a VB6 novice, I am trying to update a legacy version of an application. However, the following code arises:

**Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name**

Here is the code snippet:

```
Private Sub ppdatPrimaryRS_MoveComplete(ByVal adReason As ADODB.EventReasonEnum, 
ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, 
ByVal pRecordset As ADODB.Recordset)

Dim Position As Long
Position = datPrimaryRS.Recordset.AbsolutePosition
If Position = -1 Then Position = 0
datPrimaryRS.Caption = "Record: " & CStr(Position)
End Sub
```

The error points to this line:

```
Private Sub ppdatPrimaryRS_MoveComplete(ByVal adReason As ADODB.EventReasonEnum, ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, ByVal pRecordset As ADODB.Recordset)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `ByVal Recordset As ADODB.Recordset` is not the same signature as the event you are trying to delegate to this sub.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ms675134(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @OneFineDay Sorry, seems I wrote the wrong sub there. I updated the sub.

Comment: Same problem, you need the right signature

Comment: @OneFineDay Please excuse me is this is a basic question, however how may I determine the correct signature?

Comment: why have you tagged it vb.net and all the visual studios?

Comment: @Rob I was assuming .net persona may also have some vb knowledge. However that may not be the way things are done here, my apologies.

Answer (score 3):

The correct signature should be:

```
Private Sub ppdatPrimaryRS_MoveComplete(ByVal adReason As ADODB.EventReasonEnum, _
    ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, _
    ByVal pRecordset As ADODB.Recordset20)
```

More information:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222145

http://www.vbmigration.com/detknowledgebase.aspx?Id=105

Comment: while this is clearly along the right track, I now get this error: **User defined type not defined** I am using the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.0 Library

Comment: Try a reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library", then use "Imports ADODB".

Comment: Also, I added "Dim datPrimaryRS As New Recordset"

Comment: thanks for the help. I find that it works with Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.6

Comment: This solved all my problems, but it's important to note that I'd already updated to Active X Data Objects 6.0.  Still THANK you.  This was the final piece in a puzzle that took more than a day to solve.